# How do I make firefox's pagedown just go to the next page

Tags: firefox, debian, scrolling, about-config

I'm running Debian on a 400MHz machine, so everything's quite slow.  When I press `PgDn`, I see two or three flashes of what the page should look like as it's scrolling down to the next page (I assume this is to make an animation of the page scrolling down).

What can I set in `about:config` to make it so that `PgDn` just shows the next page immediately without this animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to change `general.smoothScroll` to `false`?

You also have a whole range of `general.smoothScroll.something` that you can try to disable if the first option doesn't work.

Comment: I believe you can also go into the advanced tab of the settings menu to disable smooth scroll as well.